# dangerously_set_inner_HTML in select option

Tags: reactjs

according to [this](https://docs.hyperstack.org/client-dsl/elements-and-rendering#html-entities) you can parse html inside fro example DIV or SPAN.

So, how could you parse html inside select options using dangerously_set_inner_HTML??

Thanx

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and edit your post. As for now, it is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: As far as I understand you *can* use `dangerously_set_inner_HTML` with `option` elements, too, but that won't help you because browser don't really support HTML tags in `option` elements. If you want to have dropdowns with markup you'll have to use one of the many Javascript `select` replacements, e.g. select2 or Choices.js

Comment: I agree with @DanielRikowski above... Can you update the question with a bit more in about what you are trying to achieve?  Perhaps some psudo code, and goal of the component you are building?

Comment: Actually, in the case of select component, we wanted to remove html from the option text, but finally we used regular expressions. Thanx for your answers!